# Trying to find the SHA512 value for inline js to remove unsafe-inline from CSP

Tags: content-security-policy, sha512, developer-console, unsafe-eval, unsafe-inline

The developer console only shows SHA256 value and i tried to calculate sha512 using shasum and added it to script integrity but I still see the CSP error